# How to set header on get method - android rest api

Tags: android, resty

I've used Rest api using resty.jar in my application

i get from http://beders.github.io/Resty/Resty/Examples.html

Here, get and post method are working well.

But i don't know how to add header in get method.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

i've found the solution.

need to add

**`r.withHeader("key", "value);`**

before get json response

```
Object name = r.json("http://ws.geonames.org/postalCode");
```